# Was "Baby Kangaroo's Birthday Surprise" the target of any censorship?

Tags: censorship, kangaroo-no-tanjoubi

The film "Baby Kangaroo's Birthday Surprise" (カンガルーの誕生日 - Kangaroo no Tanjoubi) was released in [February 1941](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6843/Kangaroo_no_Tanjoubi), less than a year before the Second Sino-Japanese war became the Pacific War, involving the United States and the British Empire, which included Australia.

The film was not set in any particular country, and involved non-Australian animals as well as kangaroos. For example, the main villain was a wolf, which doesn't occur in Australia.

Was the film the target of any censorship in Japan because of its use of an Australian animal?

Comment: Because "Surprise" is a **TRAP**